# Set text to bold in InstallScript

Tags: installshield, installscript

I have a dialog in an InstallScript Msi project (2008) and I'm trying to set some text in a label to **bold**, but can't seem to figure it out. I tried prefixing with {&STYLE_BOLD} (which is a predefined style), but it didn't help. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe setting the `Text Style` property from properties window should do this. Isn't it? There are so many pre-defined fonts who have got *bold* font-weight e.g. `TahomaBold10`, `TahomaBold8`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallScript MSI dialogs use InstallScript's support instead of MSI's. Thus you will need to use CtrlSetFont. See the example in the help, or in the <strike>[online help](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield14langref/LangrefCtrlSetFont_example.htm)</strike> [online help for InstallShield 2015](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/installshield22helplib.htm#StartTopic=Subsystems/installshield22langref/helplibrary/LangrefCtrlSetFont.htm) (CtrlSetFont hasn't changed in years).

Comment: Thanks! That worked! 
For future reference I'll add you need to call it AFTER calling WaitOnDialog...

Comment: This link is now broken.